# Zoho Mail SMTP Connection Timeout Issue on Ubuntu Server

Tags: python

I am writing to seek your assistance with a connectivity issue that I am experiencing while trying to use the Zoho Mail SMTP server for sending emails from an Ubuntu server.

- Email Address Used: mycustom_Email@example.com
- SMTP Server:smtp.zoho.com
- SMTP Port: 587

The issue I am encountering is a timeout error when attempting to run the code on the Ubuntu server. The same code works without any issues on a Windows environment, but for some reason, it does not work on the Ubuntu server.

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from email.header import Header
from email.utils import formataddr

sender_name= " Account Security"
smtp_server = "smtp.zoho.com"
smtp_port = 587
smtp_username = "########"
smtp_password = "PASSWORD" 
def send_reset_email(email, token,fullname):
    try:
        # Create a message
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        
        #print(Header(sender_name, 'utf-8') + f" <{smtp_username}>")
        msg["From"] = formataddr((str(Header(sender_name, 'utf-8')), smtp_username))
        msg["To"] = email
        msg["Subject"] = "Password Reset Request"

        # Compose the email body
        body = f"Dear {fullname},\n\n"
        body += "We received a request to reset your password. To proceed, please click the link below:\n\n"
        body += f"http://#####.com/reset-password?token={token}\n\n"
        body += "If you did not request this password reset, you can safely ignore this email. Your account security is important to us.\n\n"
        body += "Thank you for using our service!\n\n"
  

        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain"))

        # Connect to the SMTP server and send the email
        with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port) as server:
            server.starttls()
            server.login(smtp_username, smtp_password)
            server.sendmail(smtp_username, email, msg.as_string())

    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Failed to send reset email")

#Function to send email to the user with the verification token
def send_verification_email(email, token):
    try:
        # Create a message
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        # msg["From"] = Header(seander_name)+ f"<{smtp_username}>"
        msg["From"] = smtp_username
        msg["To"] = email
        msg["Subject"] = "Email Verification Request"

        # Compose the email body
        body = f"Dear User,\n\n"
        body += "We received a request to verify your email. To proceed, please click the link below:\n\n"
        body += f"https://########/verify_email/{token}\n\n"
        body += "If you did not request this email verification, you can safely ignore this email. Your account security is important to us.\n\n"
        body += "Thank you for using our service!\n\n"
    

        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain"))

        # Connect to the SMTP server and send the email
        with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port) as server:
            server.starttls()
            server.login(smtp_username, smtp_password)
            server.sendmail(smtp_username, email, msg.as_string())
        print("Verification email sent successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Failed to send verification email")
    
print(send_verification_email("info@####.com","123456"))
```

Comment: As an aside, your code seems to be written for Python 3.5 or earlier. The email library was overhauled in 3.6 and is now quite a bit more versatile and logical. Probably throw away what you have and start over with the [examples from the `email` documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)